# How to increment value for a specific key in a Map in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

In C++ if I declare a map like 
    std::map m

then I can increment the value for a specific key in the map in this way

```
m[key]++
```

In Java I declare a map

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
```

and I increment the value for a specific key in this way:

```
m.put(key, m.get(key).intValue() + 1)
```

My question: Is there any shortcut or better way to do this?

Comment: You dont need to call intValue method. You could define a method on your customised value (All wrapper's Integer/Double etc are immutable in java) and can say m.get(key).increment();

Comment: Where did you find it? Only Atomics have such methods

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) (Java 8+):

```
m.compute(key, (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

Comment: thanks. i did some study what have you have done here. this type of expression is very new to me. from my study i did not understand too much. it would be very helpful if you would give a simple example with your given expression. i looked out these [site_1](http://http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/04/whats-new-in-java-8-lambdas.html) and [site_2](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/08/java-8-functional-interfaces.html) .

Comment: maybe `m.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1)` would work better, so that if there where no elements mapped to k it will still be incremented.

Answer (score 8):

I've always preferred to use a [mutable int](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html) for these problems. So the code ends up looking like...

```
m.get(key).increment()
```

This avoids the unnecessary put overhead (which is small).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need  the `.intValue()` because of autoboxing, but apart from that, there is no better way to do this.

```
m.put(key, m.get(key) + 1)
```

The reason (or the problem) is that Java decided not to let classes implement their own operators (like it is possible in C++).

Comment: I think the "no better way" is relative. Performance and GC wise I would argue for my answer. Minimum dependencies and ease of deployment this wins.

Comment: Yes you are right. With "no better way" I meant while using a plain `Map<?, Integer>`. Your solution is better if using an 1:1 `Map<?, Integer>` isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the accepted answer that if there is no value for a requested key, we'll get an exception. Here are a few ways to resolve the issue using Java 8 features:

1. Using `Map.merge()`

`m.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`

If the key doesn't exist, put 1 as value, otherwise sum 1 to the value given for the key.

2. Using `Map.putIfAbsent()`

```
m.putIfAbsent(key, 1);
m.put(key, m.get(key) + 1);
```

Similar to other answers, but clearly says you need to init the value first.

3. Using `Map.compute()`

`m.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1)`

Always computing the value, providing 1 if there is nothing there yet.

4. Using `Map.getOrDefault()`

`m.put(key, m.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1)`

Gets the value if it exists or a default value otherwise, and returns that value plus one.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the `intValue` call and rely on auto-unboxing.